# Replace each captured char to *?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have email and want to replace each character between first letter and @ to *. Example:

```
john.smith@gmail.com   ->  j*********@gmail.com
```

Here is my code, but it produce one star instead of many - I stuck on it:

```js
let h="john.smith@gmail.com".replace(/(.)(.*)@/,'$1*') 

console.log(h);
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Hint: `split` on `@` and then replace all chars but one on one side with `*`. You could also use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a function that can do additional substitution on parts.

Comment: The email address is much better hidden if you use a fix number of asterisks (`*`) together with the first character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A global flag is what you are missing in your Regex.

I got this oneshot Regex that does the job:

```
"john.smith@gmail.com".replace(/(?!^)(?=.+@)./g,'*')
```

- Negative look ahead to exclude the first char.
- Positive look ahead for all chars preceding the @ char.
- Global flag to replace all captures.

```js
let h = "john.smith@gmail.com".replace(/(?!^)(?=.+@)./g,'*');

console.log(h);
```

Comment: Thanks, nice answer :) Your regexp can be even simplified to `/(?!^)(?=.+@)./g`. Answers of other people before you was also nice and caused me ["eureka" effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect) and take me out from mental deadlock, and teach me a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for the simplification tip ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the callback argument of `replace`:

```js
let h = "john.smith@gmail.com".replace(/(.)(.*)@/, (_, first, rest) =>
    first + "*".repeat(rest.length) + "@"
); 

console.log(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) in [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), e.g:

```js
const result = 'john.smith@gmail.com'.replace(
    /^(.)(.*)(@.+)$/,
    (match, ...groups) => groups[0] + '*'.repeat(groups[1].length) + groups[2]
);
     
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex will match the whole part and replace that with a star. Instead you want the regex to be able to match every char that you want to match separately. This will work:

```js
let h="john.smith@gmail.com".replace(/(?<=^.+)(?<!@.*)[^@]/g,'*') 
    
console.log(h);
```

To break the regex down:

`(?<=^.+)` will match the start of the string, the first character and any number of characters after it using a positive lookbehind. That concept will work to match the string but not be included in the resulting match.

`(?<!@.*)` is a negative lookbehind to make sure we don't match anything after the @ symbol.

`[^@]` matches any character that is not @.

`g` at the end means global, that makes it match any number of times instead of only once.

Answer (score 2):

Just writing:

```js
let e = Array.from("john.smith@gmail.com").reduce((arr, char, index) => arr.concat(arr.includes('@') || char === '@' ? char : index === 0 ? char : '*'), []).join('');

console.log(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex replacement will do:

```js
let h="john.smith@gmail.com".replace(/(?!^).(?=.*@)/g, '*') 
console.log(h);
```

**Details**

- `(?!^)` - not the start of the string
- `.` - any char but a line break char
- `(?=.*@)` - immediately to the right, there must be 0+ chars other than line break chars and then a `@`.

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dKLnjV/2).

Comment: Your regex `/(?!^)[^@](?=[^@]*@)/g` was also nice

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski As the user name may contain `@` the current one is the best from all posted solutions.

Comment: I not consider case with two @ but, I made test: `"john.s@mith@gmail.com".replace(/(?!^)(?=.+@)./g,'*')` (Samir answer) - and I get proper result - so I dont get the point - ? Idea in Samir answer was the best (and he show it first)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski You are not using Samir's solution.

Comment: Samir solution directly: `"john.s@mith@gmail.com".replace(/(?!^.)(?=.+@)./g,'*')` -> `"j**********@gmail.com"`  (run in chrome console)  - where is the problem?